# Regarding Windows update

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-update

I recently activated Windows 8.1 on a secondary laptop potato PC with 2GB of RAM and I want to prevent it from being updated to Windows 10, as that situation would be pathetic:

- In Windows Updates, I can see 128 important updates and 7 optional updates ranging in size from 2 - 2.5GB; most have "Windows 8.1" in their names and I don't see "Windows 10" anywhere

Will it update my laptop to Win 10 or are they updates to improve Windows 8.1?

Comment: If the laptop is still running Windows 8.1 try using GWX control panel to prevent Windows 10 from installing.  https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/gwx_control_panel.html   .   The secondary laptop is quite weak. in any event.

Comment: It's 100% guaranteed, due to the RAM alone, the PC will function with better performance on a Linux distro _(such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download) or one of its [flavors](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours))_. If needing to run Windows-specific applications, [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) can be used

Comment: @John that's complicated.. I will try

Comment: @JW0914 I have tried to install linux, but in an another computer. But since I have no USB i use unetbootn to make my harddrive a bootable drive. Then after restarting and going to installer from boot, it wrote windows failed to start due to a recent hardware or software change..... I thought I lost my windows. But windows was there but I couldn't install Linux.
I am so scared that I would fail in doing it and lose my data. So I just want my laptop not to get updated to windows 10. It's fine at 8.1

Comment: @Ramhound I read their answers. So I have a doubt.
Attempting to block the upgrade to Windows 10 by not installing certain updates is the incorrect approach of permanently preventing the upgrade to Windows 10. By setting the DisableOSUpgrade registry key, you block the upgrade entirely, despite any prompts to upgrade. (Copy paste from one of their answers.)

So will this prevent me from getting even Windows 8.1 improvement updates?
I just want to block windows 10, I don't need to remove all sort of updates. So will the above method remove just windows 10 update?

Comment: "GWX hat's complicated.. I will try"   <-- It is easy to install and it works. My Windows 7 VM never tries to update.

Comment: @AmitKerala - my answer to that question explains how to block the upgrade to Windows 10.  Windows 8.1 doesn’t and will not receive improvement updates.  My answer to the duplicate answers this question in its entirety

Comment: @AmitKerala Windows boot issues can be resolved in WinRE via `BootRec /FixMbr && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBcd`

Comment: I don't want to block updates inside windows 8.1 which make 8.1 version better. I just wanted to be away from windows 10. All other updates are acceptable. I am a noob, that's why i am not getting things you guys are saying